# Hive Internal Error: java.lang.RuntimeException(java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: hive

I've got below HiveRows. First one works and creates the table. Second one fails while loading.

```
--HiveRow1
"create table hotel_price_data (hotel string, room string, bus_date string, price string)
row format delimited fields terminated by '|' location '/tmp'"
--HiveRow2
"LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'C:/tmp/out.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE  hotel_price_data"
```

HiveRow1 works and can see table created in Sandbox UI.

HiveRow2, the loading part is an issue currently.

##########ERROR

```
13/07/24 19:45:55 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parsing command: LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'C:/tmp/out.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE  hotel_price_data
13/07/24 19:45:55 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parse Completed
13/07/24 19:45:55 INFO hive.log: DDL: struct hotel_price_data { string hotel, string room, string bus_date, string price}
FAILED: Hive Internal Error: java.lang.RuntimeException(java.net.UnknownHostException: **unknown host: sandbox**)
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: unknown host: sandbox
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Context.getScratchDir(Context.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Context.getExternalScratchDir(Context.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Context.getExternalTmpFileURI(Context.java:315)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.LoadSemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(LoadSemanticAnalyzer.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:243)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:909)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServer$HiveServerHandler.execute(HiveServer.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:127)
    at talenddemosjava.hive_connection_0_1.hive_connection.tHiveRow_4Process(hive_connection.java:1314)
    at talenddemosjava.hive_connection_0_1.hive_connection.tHiveRow_1Process(hive_connection.java:1245)
    at talenddemosjava.hive_connection_0_1.hive_connection.tHiveRow_2Process(hive_connection.java:1132)
    at talenddemosjava.hive_connection_0_1.hive_connection.tFileInputDelimited_1Process(hive_connection.java:1019)
    at talenddemosjava.hive_connection_0_1.hive_connection.tHiveConnection_1Process(hive_connection.java:461)
    at talenddemosjava.hive_connection_0_1.hive_connection.runJobInTOS(hive_connection.java:1628)
    at talenddemosjava.hive_connection_0_1.hive_connection.main(hive_connection.java:1494)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: **unknown host: sandbox**
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how this works on Windows, but I don't think your filepath `C:/tmp/out.txt` is correct. According to [the manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML) "a filepath can be:

- a relative path, eg: project/data1
- an absolute path, eg: /user/hive/project/data1
- a full URI with scheme and (optionally) an authority, eg: hdfs://namenode:9000/user/hive/project/data1"

The file needs to be in HDFS storage before it can be loaded using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH`. I'm guessing `C:/tmp/out.txt` refers to a file on your local storage, not in HDFS. You can use the `hdfs -put` [command to upload the file](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/file_system_shell.html#put).

Comment: Hi Lukas: Using Talend Studio for Big Data, so the file can be picked from local disk. to pick file from local disk.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Talend. What makes you think you can pick the file from local disk?